# WebAPI GET request not working with entity selection

Tags: c#, http, blazor, webapi, dataverse

I'm creating a Blazor server app that connects to our Dynamics 365 data using WebAPI. I have figured out the authorization and when I send an http request without specifying any entity selection - the request return IsSuccessStatusCode and I can view the json data. However adding any entity request information returns IsSuccessStatusCode as false.

This line of code is successful and returns all the entities in the database

```
var dataRequest = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{baseUrl}api/data/v9.2/
```

However no matter what I specify as a selection entity (I am matching the names to the ones returned in the above request) the dataRequest is always unsuccessful

```
var dataRequest = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{baseUrl}api/data/v9.2/salesorders?$select=amount");

or

var dataRequest = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{baseUrl}api/data/v9.2/accounts?$select=name");
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Hi Lance, to be sure, what's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Hi Eddie, I actually switched to the Microsoft.Graph.Beta API and its works great!